# What does "Last yeer I kudn't spel Engineer. Now I are won." mean

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the end of the slashdot.org(on 23rd jan 2015) website page there is quote

> Last yeer I kudn't spel Engineer. Now I are won

what does it mean, especially the second part **Now I are won**.

Comment: Now I am one. This is not exactly an ELU question. Imagine the quotation was spelled properly. Except it wasn't.

Comment: @AverageGatsby- Very cute.

Comment: @SrJoven If you can not understand an English phrase, then it must be a ELU question. If it is not then what is it then ?.

Comment: There is an English Language Learners Stack Exchange for those who don't understand English. Take a look at the [help] for this site for the types of questions that are encouraged for this site. Nonetheless, one is encouraged to do a cursory check and explain what research was attempted before engaging experts.

Comment: @SrJoven Thanks for the information on Language Learners site. What kind of cursory check could i have done before posting. I tried searching on google before posting few web urls indicated that it was a joke and thats it. Because, i have no clue where else i have gone apart from posting at stackexchange.

Comment: A cursory check would be to check dictionaries, thesaurus, perhaps a Google search, etc. Show your work, as it were. :)

Comment: It would be easier to understand had they not misspelled "injanear".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Translation:

> Last year I couldn't even spell "engineer" and now I am one.

This is an ancient joke—it was already current in a variety of forms when I was an undergraduate in the 1960s.

It pretends to mock the presumed communicative incompetence of engineering graduates, because their coursework emphasizes mathematics and rarely requires mastery of English style; but in fact it is largely current among engineers themselves, flaunted as a badge of their superiority to impractical and ineffective students of the humanities. These days you may see the variant "Last year I couldn't even spell 'Programmer' ..."

Comment: Yep, was well-known when I graduated (with an engineering degree) in 1972.  Usually it's spelled "injunir" or some such, though.

Comment: @HotLicks Perhaps you remember the Auburn engineer's Reading Comprehension Test? *'C m dux?' 'M r not dux, m r chikins' 'M r 2 dux, c m wangs?'*

Comment: Is this a bit like "The ELU was something of which I hadn't heard last year, and now I know that English Learners is not what it's for"?

Comment: If this were true, bridges and buildings would fall down. So, frankly, it ain't as clever as it might seem. It actually just shows how really uninformed some jokers are.

Answer (score 3):

It's deliberately mangled English as a way of mocking the (putatively low) English language skill level of engineers.  It features both bad spelling and bad grammar, making it difficult for a non-native speaker to decipher.

It's similar both to the [hillbilly reading test](http://egoode.newsvine.com/_news/2010/01/26/3811850-for-posteritys-sake-the-hillbilly-spelling-test-and-other-fun-kentuckiana-jokes) and [LOLspeak](http://ozwords.org/?p=6054), both of which are also versions of English deliberately mangled as a joke.

Comment: Other examples are "Let Stalk Strine" and "Fraffly Well Spoken", both by Afferbeck Lauder: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afferbeck_Lauder

Answer (score 2):

Regarding continuity of style, this is the answer:

> Last year i could not spell engineer. Now i am one.

[A little poem regarding computer spell checkers](http://www.latech.edu/tech/liberal-arts/geography/courses/spellchecker.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Used to be a commonly seen poster around engineering workshops - cartoon picture of a goofy apprentice with the caption underneath - *6 munfs ago I cudn't even spell enjuneer - now I are one!*

Comment: Interesting but not really an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this drawing in the late 60-ies of a not so bright looking guy, saying something like:
”Four weeks ago I kudn’t spell ungenier and now I are one”
The grammar was supposed to be that of an undereducated hillbilly.
I was looking for that picture, when I stumbled into this forum.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/432842)

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with the gist of the other online answers, there is more to it than that. I first heard this meme in the form of a humorous fake advertisement for a fly-by-night Engineering School, in which the the actor promoting the school says, "You too can be an Engineer after training by our highly qualified teaching staff!" followed by a hill-billy-type character who (obviously uncomfortable at being filmed) holding a slide-rule who says, "Three weeks ago I could not spell 'engineer!' and now I ARE one!" It appeared to me to be a spoof on the trend at the time of a growing number of "schools" to profit from suckering in people who weren't able to get into schools with better reputations and credentials.

Comment: When did you witness this?  I can attest that the joke goes back to ca 1970, and StoneyB claims it goes back into the 60s.  I doubt that the joke originated with the specific case you witnessed.

Comment: You say, ‘‘there is more to it than’’ [the other answers], but what is it? What are you contributing to the question ‘‘what does it mean?’’ that isn’t covered by the other answers?